# confusion with contract names and account names in eosio testnet

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, contract-development, contract-name

When writing contracts, the contract class in file *name_a.cpp* is defined as follows:

`class[[eosio::contract("name_a")]] name_b : public contract {..}`

In my understanding the name of the class is `name_b` and the contract is called `name_a`.

The contract is then deployed to the testnet with the following command with an account named `name_c`:

`cleos -u https://testnet.waxsweden.org set contract name_c /path/to/contract/ name_a.wasm name_a.abi -p name_c@active`

**What exactly is the name of this contract which must be used for transactions?**

My guess would be `name_c` as this is the name of the account that owns the contract. But what happens with the name specified in `[[eosio::contract("name_a")]]`? For what is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess would be `name_c` as this is the name of the account that owns the contract.

Correct.

> But what happens with the name specified in `[[eosio::contract("name_a")]]`? For what is it used?

Let's say your headers define multiple contract classes. e.g.

```
struct [[eosio::contract("contract.1")]] class_1 : eosio::contract
{
   using eosio::contract::contract;
   [[eosio::action]] void act1() {}
};

struct [[eosio::contract("contract.1")]] class_2 : eosio::contract
{
   using eosio::contract::contract;
   [[eosio::action]] void act2() {}
};

struct [[eosio::contract("contract.2")]] class_3 : eosio::contract
{
   using eosio::contract::contract;
   [[eosio::action]] void act3() {}
};
```

You could do this for multiple reasons:

- You want to split up your code into multiple classes.
- You include another contract's headers to make it easier to create inline actions to it.

The compiler matches the name in `[[eosio::contract("name")]]` against the command-line option `-contract` to decide which classes to build into your contract.

e.g. `eosio-cpp -contract=contract.1 file.cpp` includes `act1` and `act2` in the contract, while `eosio-cpp -contract=contract.2 file.cpp` includes `act3` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! When referring to a specific action of a specific contract by on-notify, would you also use the name of the account that owns the contract? In my example: [[eosio::on_notify("name_c::someAction")]] ?

Comment: yes, it needs the actual account name